# How can I get nginx reverse proxy to work with java applet that checks document base?

Tags: nginx, java, reverse-proxy

So I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy with nginx to a java applet on remote server, but the problem I'm having is that it checks the document base, I can get it to load from `http://remote.example.com/` just fine, but when I try to get it to run through nginx which uses the actual domain I'm trying to use, `http://newdomain.example.com`, it throws an error because the document base is not remote.

Is there a way that i can modify the reverse proxy config to pass `http://remote.example.com/` instead of the `http://newdomain.example.com/`?

Here is my config so far

```
upstream test {
    server remote.example.com:80;
}

server {

    listen       *:80;
    server_name  http://newdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://test;
        proxy_pass_request_headers              on;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_connect_timeout   180;
        proxy_send_timeout      180;
        proxy_read_timeout      180;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `Host` header from

```
proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
```

to

```
proxy_set_header        Host            remote.example.com;
```

---

*Looks like I misinterpreted your sentences about **document base**. I thought it was a protection from java applet server so, it can't be downloaded unless we change the `Host` header. Apparently, document base that you are talking about is java `getDocumentBase` function. Since java applet was executed by the browser then there are nothing we can do on server side.*

Comment: I have changed the  host header as posted, however the java applet still displays the error that it is being loaded from an incorrect url

Comment: See updated answer and sorry for the confusion

Comment: Oh, is there maybe a way to mask the URL with nginx?

Comment: No. Java applet is downloaded then browser will execute it. This happens in the client side